# Cipher suits for TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I have scan my website using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and found that our sites has below cipher suites:

## TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 128 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS 128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d) WEAK 256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c) WEAK 128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d) WEAK 256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) WEAK 256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c) WEAK 128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) WEAK 128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) WEAK 112

But I want to change this cipher suits for TLS 1.2

So can anyone guide me that how to change cipher suites?

Comment: Why would you intentionally add weak suites that don't support forward secrecy?  If a connecting client is out of date, **update the client**, don't downgrade the server...

Comment: I want to know that how to change cipher suites? and where this cipher suites are set?

Answer (score 1):

If your Server is Windows then launch gpedit.msc:

Then Navigate to:
Local Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Network > SSL Configuration Settings   -> SSL Cipher Suite Order

Obviously you will have to be Admin user.